# Pass Dataframe Row Values Iteratively (loop) as Arguments in a Function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a function that requires three arguments:

```
def R0(confirm, suspect,t):
    p = 0.695
    si = 7.5
    yt = suspect * p + confirm
    lamda = math.log(yt)/t
    R0 = 1 + lamda * si + p * (1 - p) * pow(lamda * si,2)   
    return R0
```

And a dataframe with three columns:

```
data = {'confirm':  ['41', '41', '43', '44'],
        'suspect': ['0', '0', '0', '10'],
        't': ['0', '1', '2', '3']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['confirm','suspect', 't'])
```

I would like to use each row (with three columns, and hence three values) as the argument values for the function. Finally, I would like to loop over rows of the dataframe and return a list.

For instance, the results should look like:

```
result = [R0_Value1, R0_Value2, R0_Value3, ....] where
```

```
R0_Value1 = R0(41, 0, 0)
R0_Value2 = R0(41, 0, 1)
R0_Value3 = R0(43, 0, 2)
...
```

I figure out it probably has something to do with `pandas.DataFrame.apply` and `*`. But I am new to Python and could not figure out how to do it. Could someone please help?

Comment: Should it really be in the dataframe though? Much easier and I think a bit faster if you process *outside* the dataframe.

Comment: Hi Jerome, I am not sure how to process outside the dataframe. The dataframe is actually loaded from a csv file. A friend gives me a hint and I posted an answer that solves the answer. Thank you for your fast response. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were looking in the right direction with 'apply':

```
# Convert values to int (now strings, which will throw an error in R0)
df = df.applymap(int)

df['results'] = df.apply(lambda x: R0(x.confirm, x.suspect, x.t), axis=1)
```

What happens when you use the apply function is that (in case of axis=1) the whole row is used as the first argument in the specified function. The lambda function is basically a wrapper that transforms this single argument (x) into the three unpacked values and passes them in the correct order to the next function, R0.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```py
df["formula"]=df.apply(lambda x: R0(*x), axis=1)
```

The whole thing (there were couple of other things in need of polishing):

```py
import pandas as pd
import math

def R0(confirm, suspect,t):
    p = 0.695
    si = 7.5
    yt = suspect * p + confirm
    lamda = math.log(yt)/max(t,1) #you need to handle division by 0 somehow
    R= 1 + lamda * si + p * (1 - p) * math.pow((lamda * si),2)
    return R

data = {'confirm':  ['41', '41', '43', '44'],
        'suspect': ['0', '0', '0', '10'],
        't': ['0', '1', '2', '3']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['confirm','suspect', 't']).astype(int) #note it has to be numeric to conduct all the arithmetics you are doing later

df["formula"]=df.apply(lambda x: R0(*x), axis=1)
```

Outputs:

```py
   confirm  suspect  t     formula
0       41        0  0  193.285511
1       41        0  1  193.285511
2       43        0  2   57.274157
3       44       10  3   31.297989
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist of using `pandas`, you can also do the calculations directly using `numpy` without a function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['confirm','suspect', 't']).astype(int)

p = 0.695
si = 7.5

df['results'] = 1 +(np.log(df["suspect"]*p + df["confirm"])/df["t"])*si \
                  + p*(1-p)*np.power((np.log(df["suspect"]*p + df["confirm"])/df["t"])*si,2)
print (df)

#
   confirm  suspect  t     results
0       41        0  0         inf
1       41        0  1  193.285511
2       43        0  2   57.274157
3       44       10  3   31.297989
```

Answer (score 0):

`df.apply(lambda x: R0(x[0], x[1], x[2]), axis=1)` will give the right result.

Comment: It will, only if you make sure your dataframe is using numerical values. Your values above are strings, which will throw off your apply. Additionally, it will encounter an infinite value on the first row because of division by zero.